# \afterpage and \endfloat

Tags: latex

How do I combine `\afterpage` and `\endfloat` to easily switch between having figures and tables at the end of the document or having them in the text?

I want to easily choose between my figures at the end of the document and my figures in the text. Because of that, sometimes I will use `\afterpage` package and other times I will use `\endfloat` would be nice to combine both.

Right now, all the times I try to run `\endfloat` when I have a clear page, I get the following message:

> Argument of \efloat@xfloat has an extra }.

I already tried to include after page in the DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor, something like:

> \DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{afterpage}{figure}

It did not work.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{afterpage}

% ---------------------
%figures at the end
% ---------------------
\usepackage[nolists]{endfloat}
    % force landscape at the end

\begin{document}
    {\afterpage{
    \begin{figure}

    \end{figure}
    }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is your goal to have both figures in text and at the end of the the document or do you want to switch between having all figures in the text and having all figures at the end?

Comment: I want to switch :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to switch between having figures within the text and at the end, I suggest to only use the `endfloat` package. Commenting or commenting it's optional argument `disable` will allow you to quickly alternate between figures at the end or in the text.

I'm not entirely certain what the purpose of `afterpage` was in your example, but if you used it to move the figure to a separate page, this can conveniently be done with the `p` floating specifier.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
disable
]{endfloat}

\begin{document}

test

\begin{figure}[p]
xxx
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}

test
\end{document}
```